# onTextChanged, generated CheckBox is getting added to the same row in ListView

Tags: android, listview

So based on if the user's input is above six in the EditText of the ListView, I want to add a CheckBox in the same row of the ListView. However it keeps adding it to the first row. I feel like this is suppose to be something simple, but I can't figure it out after searching other posts.

Another question. Is the best way to get the data from each item in the ListView is to store it in a ArrayList? or is there something else in terms of getting the values from all the TextView/Spinner/CheckBox?

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            final ComboView comboView;
            if(view == null){
                comboView = new ComboView();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = InputCombos.this.getLayoutInflater();
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_combos_view, null);
                comboView.combo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.combo);
                comboView.numOrbs = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.numOrbs);
                comboView.comboEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.comboEdit);
                comboView.comboElement = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.comboElement);

                ArrayAdapter<String> comboElements = new ArrayAdapter<>(InputCombos.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, elements);
                comboElements.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                comboView.comboElement.setAdapter(comboElements);

                comboView.pos = i;

                comboView.comboEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        if(charSequence.length() != 0){
                            int orbCount = Integer.parseInt((charSequence).toString());
                            if(orbCount >= 6){
                                LinearLayout comboViewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.comboViewLayout);
                                comboView.row = new CheckBox(InputCombos.this);
                                //CheckBox row = new CheckBox(InputCombos.this);
                                comboView.row.setText("Row");
                                comboViewLayout.addView(comboView.row);
                            }
                            comboData.set(comboView.pos,orbCount);
                            System.out.println(comboData);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                    }
                });

                view.setTag(comboView);
            } else {
                comboView = (ComboView) view.getTag();
            }

            System.out.println(combosNum);
            comboView.combo.setText(combosNum.get(i));

            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If a layout id is found multiple times (as it is the case if you have multiple rows with the same layout), Android will return the first occurrence that it can find: row 1.

```
LinearLayout comboViewLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.comboViewLayout);
```

Instead you should only look for it in the current row

```
LinearLayout comboViewLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.comboViewLayout);
```

Comment: Ah I did indeed though to maybe try that, but it said something about setting the view to be final, wasn't sure if that was a good thing or not. Guess I should had tried it first... Thank you.

Comment: Setting a variable to final is usually not a bad idea. In your case you probably have to introduce a new final variable to which you assign the value of view. view itself cannot be set to final in your case.